# Add function import functionality seems to be broken in EF6

Tags: visual-studio-2010, entity-framework

I am trying to import a function into my entity model. I am running VS 2012, using Entity Framework 6 with the according tools and yet no stored procedures or function names appear under the relevant drop down in the "Add Function Import" dialog.

Does anyone else have this issue? If so, does anyone have a solution?

Comment: I'm seeing the same behavior, I cannot add a sproc, because there are none in the list. Did you ever figure this out please?

Answer (score 0):

Check your database user permissions, I think it needs ddladmin, at least that fixed it for me.